# How to put two input in two seperate textfield with using a button in Java?

Tags: java, calculator

Im building a basic calculator using jswing and I have two textfield, one for input #1 and for input #2. The question is, how can I continue putting my input so that when I finished entering my first input it should go to the next textfield for my second input? And also theres seems to be an error when operating the arithmetic formulation, the output displays the wrong answer or the total of two inputs.

```
import java.awt.event.*;


class Kalkuleytor implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame f;
    JTextField t1, t2, t3;
    JLabel lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, lbl4;
    JButton one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,zero,add,mltply,sbtrct,dvd,equal;

    static double a=0,b=0,c=0,result=0;
    static int operator=0;

    Kalkuleytor()
    {
        f=new JFrame("Calculator");
        t1=new JTextField();
        t2=new JTextField();
        t3=new JTextField();
        lbl1=new JLabel("Number 1");
        lbl2=new JLabel("Number 2");
        lbl3=new JLabel("");
        lbl4=new JLabel("Total");
        one=new JButton("1");
        two=new JButton("2");
        three=new JButton("3");
        four=new JButton("4");
        five=new JButton("5");
        six=new JButton("6");
        seven=new JButton("7");
        eight=new JButton("8");
        nine=new JButton("9");
        zero=new JButton("0");
        dvd=new JButton("/");
        mltply=new JButton("*");
        sbtrct=new JButton("-");
        add=new JButton("+");
        equal=new JButton("=");

        //setBounds and add of buttons

        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(517,502);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setResizable(false);

        one.addActionListener(this);
    //ActionListener for all button
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==one)
            t1.setText("1");

        if(e.getSource()==two)
            t1.setText("2");

        if(e.getSource()==three)
            t1.setText("3");

        if(e.getSource()==four)
            t1.setText("4");

        if(e.getSource()==five)
            t1.setText("5");

        if(e.getSource()==six)
            t1.setText("6");

        if(e.getSource()==seven)
            t1.setText("7");

        if(e.getSource()==eight)
            t1.setText("8");

        if(e.getSource()==nine)
            t1.setText("9");

        if(e.getSource()==zero)
            t1.setText("0");

        if(e.getSource()==add)
        {
            a=Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
            operator=1;
            lbl3.setText("+");
        } 

        if(e.getSource()==sbtrct)
        {
            a=Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
            operator=2;
            lbl3.setText("-");
        }

        if(e.getSource()==mltply)
        {
            a=Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
            operator=3;
            lbl3.setText("*");
        }

        if(e.getSource()==dvd)
        {
            a=Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
            operator=4;
            lbl3.setText("/");
        }

        if(e.getSource()==equal)
        {
            c=Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());

            switch(operator)
            {
                case 1: result=a+b;
                    break;

                case 2: result=a-b;
                    break;

                case 3: result=a*b;
                    break;

                case 4: result=a/b;
                    break;

                default: result=0;
            }

            t3.setText(""+result);
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new Kalkuleytor();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRe3Z.png)

Comment: For your first question, you may want to call `requestFocus()`  on the second textfield

Comment: @Arnaud use of requestFocus is discouraged as its behaviour is platform dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [requestFocusInWindow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow()) after you click on any operator (+,-,*,/,etc).

Comment: For your second question, I believe you are learning and would suggest you to use debugger, also would like to give a hint that I am not able to see anywhere you are setting value of variable b except initialization.

Answer (score 1):

1. To give the focus to an input you may use [`requestFocusInWindow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow())
2. The wrong result may come from that you used the wrong variable, in the `equal` if, you read the text into `c` and use `b` in the computations :

   ```
   if (e.getSource() == equal) {
       b = Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
       switch (operator) {
       //...
   ```

---

Also you may simplify your code, you can easily refactor it:

- use `else if` when you can, like to get the number from the button, it can be one case only, don't try all, same for operators

  ```
  if(e.getSource()==one)
      t1.setText("1");
  else if(e.getSource()==two)
      t1.setText("2");
  ```
- You may directly read the JButton text from it and use it, don't try all possibilities

  ```
  Object source = e.getSource();
  if (source instanceof JButton) {
      JButton btn = (JButton) source;
      String textStr = btn.getText();
      if (textStr.matches("\\d")) {
          t1.setText(textStr);
      } else {
          lbl3.setText(textStr);
          a = Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
          operator = textStr;
      }
  }
  ```
- You may also directly use a `String` to store the operator, don't bother you to pass to an int

  ```
  if (e.getSource() == equal) {
      b = Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
      switch (operator) {
          case "+":
              result = a + b;
              break;
          case "-":
              result = a - b;
              break;
          case "*":
              result = a * b;
              break;
          case "/":
              result = a / b;
              break;
          default:
              result = 0;
      }
      t3.setText("" + result);
  }
  ```

The [full code is here](https://pastebin.com/HwKXZui1)

---

Using more specific features, like `BiFunction` you could do :

```
    Map<String, BiFunction<Double, Double, Double>>  operators = new HashMap<>() {{
        put("+", (d1, d2) -> d1 + d2);
        put("-", (d1, d2) -> d1 - d2);
        put("*", (d1, d2) -> d1 * d2);
        put("/", (d1, d2) -> d1 / d2);
    }};
```

And

```
        } else {     // For = button
            b = Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
            result = operators.getOrDefault(operator, (d1, d2) -> 0.0).apply(a, b);
            t3.setText("" + result);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one issue in this code.

- When you enter a value greater than 9 (2 buttons before your operator button) only the last digit will remain.
- You have two textfields t1 and and t2. On button 0 to 9 you fill t1 but you never fill  t2.
- on the buttons +-*/ you convert the text in t1 to a value in the variable a but never convert the text in t2 to variable b

Textfields are for displaying so you can better use a separate variable of type String to register the input from the buttons 0-9 and concatenate them. Fill t1 of t2 depending on a boolean

Add the variables

```
String input = "";
boolean firstInput = true;
```

```
if(e.getSource()==one)
   t1.setText("1");
```

will become

```
if(e.getSource()==one){
    input += "1";
    if (firstInput ) {
        t1.setText(input);
    } 
    else {
        t2.setText(input);
    }
}
```

On the operators change

```
if(e.getSource()==add) {
   a=Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
   operator=1;
   lbl3.setText("+");
}
```

```
if(e.getSource()==add) {
   a=Double.parseDouble(input);
   operator=1;
   lbl3.setText("+");
   firstInput = false;
   input = "";
}
```

on the equal sign

```
        if(e.getSource()==equal)
        {
            c=Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());

            switch(operator)
            {
                case 1: result=a+b;
                    break;

                case 2: result=a-b;
                    break;

                case 3: result=a*b;
                    break;

                case 4: result=a/b;
                    break;

                default: result=0;
            }

            t3.setText(""+result);
        }       
    }
```

to

```
if(e.getSource()==equal) {
   b=Double.parseDouble(input);

   switch(operator)
   {
    ....
   }
   t3.setText(""+result);
   firstInput = false;
   input = "";
}
```

Comment: It displays null in the textfield

Comment: The variable input should be initialized. I have corrected the answer.